# What is this board given to a pilot in World War II?

Tags: aviation-history, pilots, wwii, us-navy

What is this board given to a pilot in World War II?

[image]

Comment: Obviously, it's an old iPhone!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The photo in the question is a screenshot from the movie "Midway"(2019).

The board is a [Mark 3A Plotting Board](https://timeandnavigation.si.edu/multimedia-asset/mark-3a-plotting-board) used for navigation by pilots flying from U.S. Navy aircraft carriers during World War II.  It can be seen carried by various [SBD Dauntless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_SBD_Dauntless) pilots in this scene from the movie ["Midway" (2019)](https://youtu.be/n07ZvaczdtA?t=24) from 0:24 to 1:07.

Photo credit: National Air and Space Museum, Smithsonian Institution
[image]

[Plotting Board Instructions](http://fer3.com/arc/imgx/Plotting-board-instructions.pdf)

[image]

Photo credit: National Air and Space Museum, Smithsonian Institution
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How would you quickly get it out of the way?

Comment: It is mounted on a sliding shelfd and can be slid out of the way.

Comment: What's the device mounted to the windshield?

Comment: Gun sight or bomb sight.

Comment: But why did it have to be brought into the cockpit before each take-off rather than just being there? Was it somehow mission-specific?

Comment: The board also serves as a map holder and different maps would be attached for each area of operation or mission.